# wordpress resizing add_image_size properly 

Tags: php, image, wordpress

I am trying to change the size of a thumbnail in wordpress, but it keeps making it exactly square even though I want to stretch the width moreso than the height.
Im not sure why this doesnt work. Any help would be great
In functions I have

```
// Used for large feature (header) images.
add_image_size( 'large-feature', $custom_header_support['width'], $custom_header_support['height'], true );
// Used for featured posts if a large-feature doesn't exist.
add_image_size( 'small-feature', 500, 300 );
```

and below

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
add_image_size( 'results-thumb', 70, 55, true); 

}
```

and where im calling the thumbnail...

```
<?php echo the_post_thumbnail('results-thumb'); ?>
```

Heres the site, at the bottom in the latest results section you'll see the thumbnails..
http://limerickfc.hailstormcommerce.com/cms/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just fixed it with css workaround by applying a `min-width` rule to the containing div, although Im still not sure this is the best way to go about it. But I wont accept the answer yet as Im sure Ill run into this situation again

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to regenerate the sizes. Try installing and running this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/